# 'Help' The primary key column cannot be generated by the server

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, linq

My create table code like :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeTai](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MaDeTai]  AS ('DT'+right('000000'+CONVERT([varchar](10),[ID]),(6))) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
[TenDeTai] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[LinhVuc] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[Nam] [int] NOT NULL,
[MaGV] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
)
```

When I use linq to sql to insert a values this messages come out

> The primary key column of type `'VarChar(8)'` cannot be generated by the server.

what should i do ?

Comment: Where do you declare the primary key?

Comment: there is a comma too much, right after your last field

Comment: and like @stuartd already said you dont create any primary key at all

Comment: Looking at your table, the ID field is almost certainly what you want to use for a primary key - but you have to explicitly state the primary key...

Comment: sr I already set primary key for [MaDeTai] tks  but it's skill not work at all I still have that error message :(

Comment: update your question than and show us the actual create statement

Answer (score 0):

you have to designate the primary key, setting identity is not enough

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeTai](
  [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [MaDeTai]  AS ('DT'+right('000000'+CONVERT([varchar](10),[ID]),(6))) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
  [TenDeTai] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
  [LinhVuc] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
  [Nam] [int] NOT NULL,
  [MaGV] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,

  constraint PK_DeTail_ID primary key (ID)
)
```

Comment: sr I forgot (Primary key (MaDeTai)) but it's still not working :(